# Find four points around a GameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to wrap my head around what appears to be quite a simple problem.

I want to get four points around a game object. The object may be made up of multiple child primitives such as cylinders and boxes. I should point out that the parent object does not have a renderer. Here's an illustration:

[image]

I am able to get the four points by iterating the children's renderers, and encapsulating their bounds like so.

```
    private Bounds GetBounds()
    {
        var renderers = GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>();
        Bounds bounds = renderers[0].bounds;

        for (int i = 1; i < renderers.Length; i++)
            bounds.Encapsulate(renderers[i].bounds);

        return bounds;
    }
```

The problem with this method is that bounds do not take into account rotation. I'd like the points to track the points on the game object regardless of rotation.

I had also considered placing a number of game objects within the prefab which served as each point, but I'd like to be able to do this programmatically.

Comment: Maybe you can create a custom struct with bound and quaternion and set the rotation when the struct initialized.

Comment: Add those positions as empty child game objects. They will then rotate with the parent object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you are looking for those min/max bounds points regardless of the parent objects orientation.

One general "issue" with the bounds is that they will always be world axis aligned.

So what you could do is

- store parents rotation

  ```
  var rotation = transform.rotation;
  ```
- reset parents rotation

  ```
  transform.rotation = Quaternion.identity;
  ```
- now calculate the bounds

  ```
  var renderers = GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>();
  var bounds = renderers[0].bounds;
  for (int i = 1; i < renderers.Length; i++)
      bounds.Encapsulate(renderers[i].bounds);
  ```
- calculate the points (from the image I assumed XY for now but you can adjust accordingly)

  ```
  Vector2 center = bounds.center;
  Vector2 min = bounds.min;
  Vector2 max = bounds.max;

  Vector2 left = center:
  left.x = min.x;

  Vector2 right = center;
  right.x = max.x;

  Vector2 top = center;
  top.y = max.y;

  Vector2 bottom = center;
  bottom.y = min.y;
  ```
- convert them into local space of the parent

  ```
  left = transform.InverseTransformPoint(left);
  right = transform.InverseTransformPoint(right);
  top = transform.InverseTransformPoint(top);
  bottom  = transform.InverseTransformPoint(bottom);
  ```
- apply rotation back to parent

  ```
  transform.rotation = rotation;
  ```
- convert again into world space (if needed at all)

  ```
  left = transform.TransformPoint(left);
  right = transform.TransformPoint(right);
  top = transform.TransformPoint(top);
  bottom = transform.TransformPoint(bottom);
  ```

This way you get clean(er) world space bound positions, always calculated in a world axis aligned space but then rotated back to the actual orientation of the parent